# oracle connectivity

Tags: java

```
String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
String portNumber = "1521";
String sid = "database";
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
String username = "scott";
String password = "tiger";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Could not connect to the database

Comment: And your question would be ... ?

Answer (score 2):

The mother of all connection string sites: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle

Comment: It appears to me, as the linked website is ADO(.NET) specific. Do the same connection strings work with JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is "what's wrong with this picture", perhaps you overlooked including the JDBC JAR Driver in the classpath?